# Copy direct children and their attributes only in XSLT 1.0?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Input XML:

```
<root>
  <recordList>
    <record priref="1">
      <Group attr="val">
        <Field1>Value X</Field1>
        <Field2>
          <value lang="en-US">Foo</value>
          <value lang="de-DE">Bar</value>
        </Field2>
      </Group>
      <Field3 attr="val">Value Y</Field3>
    </record>
    <record priref="2">
      <Field3 attr="val">Value Z</Field3>
    </record>
  </recordList>
</root>
```

Desired output (kind of a "shallow copy" with only the immediate child elements and attributes):

```
<root>
  <record priref="1">
    <Group attr="val" />
    <Field3 attr="val">Value Y</Field3>
  </record>
  <record priref="2">
    <Field3 attr="val">Value Z</Field3>
  </record>
</root>
```

Is there another way (e.g. without for-each) to achieve this?

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <root>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="root/recordList/record" />
  </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="record">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@* | text()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

**edit:** the text nodes "Value Y" and "Value Z" are actually supposed to be in the result. "Foo" and "Bar" are still not desired anywhere in the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simply not apply templates to nodes you don't want?

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="recordList">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="record/*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|text()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Accepted, because it looks like the cleanest approach of all. I removed the recordList template, which is not needed here.

Comment: @CoDEmanX The template IS necessary to get the output shown in your question.

Comment: You are right, I had not noticed the presence of the `<recordList>` element in the output without that template.

Answer (score 1):

A very short template uses the `parent::`-axis:

```
<xsl:template match="root|record|*[parent::record]|*[parent::record]/text()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()" />
```

It's output is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <record priref="1">
    <Group attr="val">
    </Group>
  <Field3 attr="val">Value Y</Field3></record>
  <record priref="2">
    <Field3 attr="val">Value Z</Field3>
  </record>
</root>
```

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake in the desired output (see my edited question). With your solution, the result is `<Group attr="val">Value XFooBar</Group>` (all text nodes concatenated) and `<Field3 attr="val" />` (no text node), but what I'm looking for is `<Group attr="val" />` (empty node, no text children) and `<Field3 attr="val">Value Y</Field3>` (with text child).

Answer (score 1):

One way is to not process any grandchildren:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="recordList">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="record/*/node()"/>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Good thinking. If I adjust the last template to `record/*/*`, the result looks like my (updated) desired output! Together with `<xsl:template match="/"><root><xsl:apply-templates select="root/recordList/record" /></root></xsl:template>` it is perfect (there are elements adjacent to recordList that I want to exclude, including their text nodes). Thanks!

Comment: I had the `record/*/*` first, but then changed it to `record/*/node()` as your requested output at some stage seemed to have empty `Field3`. But the approach is the important step.